How to backup and restore Windows Input Language Hot keys?
I reinstall Windows relatively frequent.
Is there a way to backup the Input Language hot keys, and restore them automatically ?
Plus if I can add these keyboards back automatically, that would be even better.
These are the hotkeys I'm using:


If it exists anywhere it would be in the registry, as a test, create a new user. As the hot keys you created there for the new user? This will tell us where in the registry it would be contained

Perhaps these two links can help you find the registry keys.

Or even easier than creating a new user -- user RegistryChangesView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html, or similar tool to diff the Registry before and after changes.

Thanks for the suggestions. I'm using RegistryChangesView to create and compare snapshots. So far I found some interesting changes. I'll update this thread when my testing find some conclusive cases.

So after some testing I found out :
Import the backup .reg file of
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout]

After reboot, the Keyboard layouts will be added.
(thus Win + Space) can switch to and use them.
Import the backup of
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method] ; or maybe only need :
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\Hot Keys]  

After reboot, the hotkeys start working.
Import the backup of
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International] ; or maybe just :
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile]

Then after reboot, those different language and keyboards would be properly added into the system, and show up in Settings -> Lanuage.
If you have some input methods are added by 3-rd party installers, better install those first.
(For example the Google Japanese Input in my list)
I just backup the 3 main keys, and tried to import them back with different combinations.
All 3 combined worked well for me.
